# Cannot return mutable reference to member from a match arm

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

As an exercise in rust borrowing and lifetimes, I want to implement a simple binary tree. However, I am stuck on something. Consider this:

```
struct Node {
    key: i32,
    value: i32,
    left: Option<Box<Node>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

struct BinaryTree {
     root: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

impl BinaryTree {

    fn find_mut(&mut self, key: i32) -> &mut Option<Box<Node>> {
        let mut node = &mut self.root;
        loop {
            match node {
                Some(box_node) if box_node.key != key => {
                    node = if box_node.key < key {
                        &mut box_node.right
                    } else {
                        &mut box_node.left
                    }
                },
                other => return other
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above fails to compile with:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `node` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:40:17
   |
29 |     fn find_mut(&mut self, key: i32) -> &mut Option<Box<Node>> {
   |                 - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
33 |                 Some(box_node) if box_node.key != key => {
   |                      -------- borrow of `node.0` occurs here
...
40 |                 other => return other
   |                 ^^^^^           ----- returning this value requires that `node.0` is borrowed for `'1`
   |                 |
   |                 move out of `node` occurs here
```

I tried explicitly setting the lifetime for `self` and the output. I also tried to expand the `Some(_)` arm and match for `None` instead of `other` as well.

(Edit 2): The purpose of `find_mut` is to return a ref to the object where a new node should be created (in case the key is not found) or where the existing node is.

What is the reason for the compile error, in more detail? How should I go to fix it? Is what I am trying to do even a good practice, (edit 1) i.e. return ref to the Optional where the modification should be at (assuming this is not a public method)?

Comment: I think you found a known limitation of the borrow checked, related to the lifetimes of returned borrows. FWIW, it compiles with `-Z polonius` in nightly, so I expect a future version of the compiler will accept it. Something like this [github issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/68117).

Answer (score 2):

The reason why Rust compiler issues error is because `Some(expr)` pattern matches the whole expression in its owned form, that is, `expr` is moved.

Usually, that is easily solved by matching on expression as a borrow `Some(ref expr)`, or mutable borrow `Some(ref mut expr)`, but that is not the case here.

If you look at standard library, you will often see that `as_mut()`/`as_ref()`, when value may not exist, always returns `Option<&mut T>` rather than `&mut Option<T>`. That's because you really want to access the value, not any innards of the data structure, which constructs like `Option<Box<None>>` are.

Following that, I came up with this:

```
struct Node {
    key: i32,
    value: i32,
    left: Option<Box<Node>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

struct BinaryTree {
     root: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

impl BinaryTree {
    fn find_mut(&mut self, key: i32) -> Option<&mut Node> {
        // &mut Option<Box<Node>> -> Option<&mut Box<Node>> -> Option<&mut Node>
        let mut node = self.root.as_mut().map(|boxed| boxed.as_mut());
        loop {
            match node {
                Some(box_node) if box_node.key != key => {
                    node = if box_node.key < key {
                        box_node.right.as_mut().map(|boxed| boxed.as_mut())
                    } else {
                        box_node.left.as_mut().map(|boxed| boxed.as_mut())
                    }
                },
                other => return other
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There might be a nicer way to write this, but I am not aware of it at the moment.

Note that this solves both the issue with ownership, since now `&mut Node` is what is being moved here, and makes the API nicer at the same time.

As to whether its good practice, given its double meaning, yes and no.

It helps you learn how to deal with borrows; on the other hand, we already have [`Vec::binary_search`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.binary_search), and [`BTreeMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html)/[`BTreeSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html), and its likely that on [`crates.io`](https://crates.io/search?q=search%20tree) there are other implementations that should cover all but the most extreme cases and there's little point in making a search tree yourself.

Comment: It would be nice to understand _why_ mutable borrow like `Some(ref mut box_node)` doesn't help here. I agree that returning `Option<&mut T>` is nicer than returning `&mut Option<T>`, but it's not intuitively clear to me why the latter wouldn't work. After all, the OP's data structures do consistently contain `Option<Box<Node>>`, so it looks ok to return a reference to one of them, with the lifetime of the tree.

Comment: @user4815162342 I'm not sure how to explain it so anyone can understand, but essentially `acquire borrow` -> `acquire borrow that is referencing data through a borrow before` -> `initial borrow drops (but you want to keep a second borrow, that depends on first one)`, which is pretty much what compiler will tell you if you try to modify original code and use `Some(ref mut box_node)`. Now, that wouldn't be an issue with pointers, "sadly", references inherit lifetime bounds from their ancestors and that doesn't quite work as you'd want it to.

Comment: I thought the second borrow would just inherit the lifetime of the first borrow (in this case the lifetime of the whole tree). Still, I tried to modify the code to use `Some(ref mut box_node)`, but the compiler just complained about moving out of the other match arm. When I [added](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=35d1ebeaf76d0140d3d047c45a310017) the `ref mut` to the other match arm, the compiler started to complain about two mutable borrows, which I don't quite understand as the two should never exist in parallel.

Comment: @user4815162342 the issue, as I mentioned, is that a borrow from a borrow inherits lifetime of a former borrow, and in this case, former borrow exists purely in this method, or rather, inside the match, and cannot outlive it. If there's a safe way to tell rust that it's not the case I'm not aware of it (you can look at what `as_mut` does), that is why instead of double borrow, I extracted a single final borrow preemptively and everything just clicked into their places.

Comment: Interestingly, according to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63428868/cannot-return-mutable-reference-to-member-from-a-match-arm/63429462?noredirect=1#comment112165097_63428868) by rodrigo, the experimental Polonius borrow checker accepts the code even without the `ref mut`.

Comment: And that is correct. If you used pointers (lifetimes are your problem), given this code, that would be sound. Polonius must be able to perform deeper analysis. The `ref mut` being optional is weird though, either it ignores ownership semantics, or borrows implicitly.

Comment: You can also use `Option::as_deref_mut(&mut Option<Box<Node>>) -> Option<&mut Node>`